# GLFW Extreme values

Tags: java, glfw

GLFW wont let me have a screen resolution of 32 pixels by 16 pixels. I want to see what an extremely bad resolution would look like on a game. So is there a way to not let the system override extreme screen resolution values?

I tried GLFW.glfwSetWindowSizeLimits(this.window, 0, 0, 10000, 10000);

Comment: Can we please get a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

The GLFW doc under [glfwSetWindowSize](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__window.html#ga371911f12c74c504dd8d47d832d095cb) states:

> "The window manager may put limits on what sizes are allowed. GLFW
> cannot and should not override these limits"

If the window manager is what you refer to as the "system". Then i guess the
answer is pretty final.

You could check for errors after the glfwSetWindowSizeLimits() call: GLFW_INVALID_VALUE or GLFW_PLATFORM_ERROR.

Could be an error message (if any) gives you something.

But given the reason for you asking, you could render to a 32x16px framebuffer instead of the default framebuffer.

Then render that as a 32x16px quad onto the default framebuffer.